# Custom cursor image is not working after redirecting application url from http to https

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, https, custom-cursor

I redirect my application url from  http to https . I am using custom cursor images for the cursor at some area in my application. Before redirecting http to https it was working fine , mean i am able to get that  custom cursor images in my page. i defined url for this cursor images inside js file . I am new to this things .  Can anyone help me to solve this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably need to replace `http://domain.tld/cursor.png` with just `//domain.tld/cursor.png`

Comment: Check if the images of the cursor themselves are shttp. If they aren't Https, they might not work.

Comment: There seems to be differing opinions on the use of `//` now - https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/588502455530311680?lang=en-gb

Comment: i am using url format like "../abc/images/picture.cur " .

Comment: i used like this >  $("canvas").css({cursor: 'url(../folder/folder1/image.cur), auto'});

Answer (score 0):

When you are using https, all other resources that you use must also be secure like css files, javascripts, images, ...

So you should change the links to your resources to start with either `https://` or `//`.

If you start your links with `//` it would translate to http:// when pages is loaded with http and will translate to https:// when loaded using secure connection. example:

change your link like this:

`<img src="http://domain.com/images/image.png">` to `<img src="//domain.com/images/image.png">`

and `<link type="text/css" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />` to `<link type="text/css" href="//domain.com/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

**Edit:**

If you images are defined in css files correcting your css link will do, otherwise you should use absolute url.

If you use the way you mentoined in comment 
`$("canvas").css({cursor: 'url(../folder/folder1/image.cur), auto'});`

I suggest adding it in a class in css like:

`.custom-cursor{url(../folder/folder1/image.cur)}`

and then using it like:

`$("canvas"). addClass('custom-cursor');`

Comment: thank for your instant reply . my url is in this format "../images/cursor/image.cur" and one more point it can able to fatch other png images .

Comment: are these urls in your css or the page itself?

Comment: @chintanbhut I edited my answer please have a look a it

Comment: thesee urls are in the page it self not in css . thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer, look at the edit part in my answer

Comment: thesee urls are in the page it self not in css . I am using IE  ,  i heard that for IE url must be relative to the page not to the CSS. I might be wrong .  thanks